# How to install Virtual PC 2007 additions?

Tags: windows-7, virtual-machine, virtualization, microsoft-virtual-pc

I have Windows 7 Home edition 64 in my Physical Machine. I download and install Virtual PC 2007 and install a Windows XP in a virtual machine.

I want to share a folder between physical machine and virtual machine.
But I don't know how to install virtual machine additions.

I've search for a download link but I can't find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i find it!
there are an iso file in this location:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Virtual PC\Virtual Machine Additions\VMAdditions.iso
```

this is whatever i wanted.
thanks